# Unable to obtain values if for loop placed in a different line of code

Tags: java

I'm tasked to take the words out of a txt file and then eliminate the duplicates and print out the rest. However there seems to be something weird going on when I place the for loop used to print out the array of words that are taken from the txt file.

When I do

```
for (String word:arr) 
    {
        words = word.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
            // Printing the elements of String array
            System.out.print(words[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

where, arr is an array of string; filled with sentences from the text file , and words is the individual words of the text file stored in array of strings, printing the array words will give what it is supposed to,

however when I do

```
    for (String word:arr) 
    {
        words = word.split(" ");    
    }// not nested so happens seperately
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
    {
        // Printing the elements of String array
        System.out.print(words[i] + " ");
    }
```

I only obtain 4 words out of the hundreds that are stored in the txt file.

Can someone help explain this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i understand that your learning but try to use site after going thru [faq] else u will get downvoted/ questions closed. i hope u progress in your learning and use stackoverflow the way its meant to be. please close this question & go thru a good tutorial or two. both written & video

Comment: using any good IDE and their formatter option, you would see that in the second snippet, the for-blocks are not nested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case you are processing outside of the first for, and you process just the last String that is in your array. Words variable gets overwritten in each itteration. My suggestion is to learn how to debug, it will greatly help you to learn.